# repeating previous regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a line (and a arbitrary number of them)
0    1   1   75     55

I can get it by doing

```
x = re.search("\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+(\d+)", line)
    if x != None:
        print(x.group(1))
        print(x.group(2))
        print(x.group(3))
```

But there must be a neater way to write this. I was looking at the docs for something to repeat the previous expression and found (exp){m times}.

So I try

```
x = re.search("(\d+\s+){5}", line)
```

and then expect x.group(1) to be 0, 2 to be 1, 3 to be 1 and so on
but x.group(1) ouputs 55 (the last number). Im sort of confused. Thanks.

Also on a side note. Do you guys have any recommendations for online tutorials (or free to download books) on regex?

Comment: Here's a good starter for regex and Python: http://docs.python.org/howto/regex

Comment: To anyone saying to use .split(), I used re's because there was a bunch of headers to go through before the actual data, and I didn't feel like manually counting how many lines to skip before parsing :P Thanks everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered findall which repeats the search until the input string is exhausted and returns all matches in a list?

```
>>> import re
>>> line = '0 1 1 75 55'
>>> x = re.findall("(\d+)", line)
>>> print x
['0', '1', '1', '75', '55']
```

Answer (score 3):

Repetition of capturing groups [does not work, and won't any time soon](http://bugs.python.org/issue7132) (in the sense of having the ability to individually actually access the matched parts) – you will just have to write the regex the long way or use a string method such as [`.split()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/string-methods.html#l2h-262), avoiding regex altogether.

Answer (score 1):

In your regular expression, there is only one group, since you have only one pair of parentheses.  This group will return the last match, as you found out yourself.

If you want to use regular expressions, and you know the number of integers in a line in advance, I would go for

```
x = re.search("\s+".join(["(\d+)"] * 5), line)
```

in this case.

(Note that

```
x = re.search("(\d+\s+){5}", line)
```

requires a space *after* the last number.)

But for the example you gave I'd actually use

```
line = "0 1 1 75 55"
int_list = map(int, line.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

line = '0 1 2 75 55'

x = re.search('\\s+'.join(5*('(\\d+)',)), line)

if x:
    print '\n'.join(x.group(3,4,5))
```

Bof

Or, with idea of Sven Marnach:

```
print '\n'.join(line.split()[2:5])
```